# keras model.evaluate and sklearn roc_auc_score give different results

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am training a brain tumour classification model in Keras and I am interested in the AUC metric. By using keras model.evaluate with the test generator I obtain an AUC of 0.65 but, computing the AUC with sklearn roc_auc_score I obtain, 0.49, a completely different result (which does not make sense being less than 0.5) It does not make sense to me. Does it has an explanation or am I doing something wrong?

**Model:**

```
# Build model
base_model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
# Convert features of shape `base_model.output_shape[1:]` to vectors
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# A Dense classifier for binary classification
x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
```

**Compile:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC

# Configure the model for training.
model.compile(optimizer=fit_optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=['accuracy', AUC()])
```

**Evaluation with Keras:**

```
# Evaluate the model
test_generator.reset()
score = model.evaluate(test_generator, verbose=0)

print(f"Loss: {str(score[0])} \nAccuracy on test: {str(score[1])}\n AUC: {str(score[2])}")
```

**Evaluation with sklearn:**

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

pred = model.predict(test_generator, verbose=0)

# Assign most probable label
predicted_class_indices = np.round(pred)

# Get AUC
roc_auc_score(test_generator.classes, predicted_class_indices)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `roc_auc_score` usually requires an integer array of classes, and a **float** array of predicted class probabilities—which makes the `np.round(pred)` seem suspicious here. Does removing the `round` call fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly, the result seems to be the same after removing the `round`.